# Change the color of menu bar in a premium theme - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

It's being imposible for me to change the color of the menu bar of my website: vayapollo.com

I want to change it, but I've tried all. At the css archives of my theme I can't find this code:

```
#branding, .post-afterbar-a.in-post-top, .horizontal-vote a.up span {
    background-color: #ededed;
}
```

I want to change the color **#ededed** to **#000** (black). I've tried to find it at PHP or javascript archives but nothing!

The route that google chrome is giving to me is (index):64 but at the index.php file isn't the code.

Thanks, it will be a help for me!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this css comes from admin

If you are not able to find it you can add new css to overwrite this css in your css file

```
#branding, .post-afterbar-a.in-post-top, .horizontal-vote a.up span {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

Hope it will work

Comment: welcome. If you are happy with this solution then please vote me